# php logon error - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF

Tags: php, html, syntax, authentication

I'm getting the error on line 23 which is this line:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
```

Can you see my code below and see anything I've missed?

```
<?php
// Include database connection and select database UFPProducts
     include "../shopdb/connection.php";
?>
<?php
//
session_start();
// (2) Collect data from form and save in variables

$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password']; 

// (3) Create query of the form below to search the user table
//   "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName='$username' AND  Password='$password'"

"SELECT * FROM USERS where Username='$username' AND Password='$password'"

// (3) Run query through connection

// (4) Check result of query using code below

// if rows found set authenticated user to the user name entered 
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { 
$_SESSION["authenticatedUser"] = $username;
// Relocate to the logged-in page
header("Location: loggedon.php");
} 
else
// login failed redirect back to login page with error message
{
$_SESSION["message"] = "Could not connect as $username " ;
header("Location: login.php");
}
?>
```

Thank you for your time & help

Comment: Why do you have `"SELECT * FROM USERS where Username='$username' AND Password='$password'"` floating around arbitrarily in your code?

Comment: Following on from @Musa my guess is you forgot to write the rest of the query. P.s. the mysql_* functions are deprecated please look at mysqli or pdo.

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT * FROM USERS where Username='$username' AND Password='$password'";
```

Put a semicolon at the end and try

Comment: Just tried that, then I got this error:


Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent ( /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/site/login/loginAction.php on line 7

Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/site/login/loginAction.php on line 23

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/site/shopdb/connection.php:18)/site/login/loginAction.php on line 32

Comment: @BobUni session_start(); should come just after the opening php tag

Comment: thanks , I've done that and get the following:

Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/site/login/loginAction.php on line 24

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/site/shopdb/connection.php:18) in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/site/login/loginAction.php on line 33

Comment: If you are getting the error above, then try to put  `ob_start();` at the VERY beginning of your code, and I mean before the `<html>` like `<?php ob_start(); ?> <html>` after this, you can put all your code and will never see that error again.

Comment: If it worked for you, don't forget to vote up otherwise feel free to ask again.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, this way you will minimize your chances of getting your site hacked through SQL injection.

```
<?php
// Include database connection and select database UFPProducts
     include "../shopdb/connection.php";
?>
<?php
//
session_start();
// (2) Collect data from form and save in variables

$username=mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['username']));
$password=mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['password']));

// (3) Create query of the form below to search the user table
//   "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName='$username' AND  Password='$password'"

$query = "SELECT * FROM USERS where Username='$username' AND Password='$password'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error()); 

// (3) Run query through connection

// (4) Check result of query using code below

// if rows found set authenticated user to the user name entered 
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { 
$_SESSION["authenticatedUser"] = $username;
// Relocate to the logged-in page
header("Location: loggedon.php");
} 
else
// login failed redirect back to login page with error message
{
$_SESSION["message"] = "Could not connect as $username " ;
header("Location: login.php");
}
?>
```